# Receiving Swift Error: Cannot convert value of type '([PFObject]?, NSError)? Void' to expected argument type 'PFArrayResultBlock?'

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm new to swift and Xcode, so I apologize if this is a poorly asked question. I'm working on a project with a friend and when I clone the project a few of the parse framework's aren't pulled down onto my machine, which I now believe I know why. He then sent me those frameworks. Now when I reboot the project I get 7 errors that are all related to what I think is  a parse-caused problem. the error I get on all 7 of the errors is:

```
([PFObject]?, NSError)? Void' to expected argument type 'PFArrayResultBlock?
```

It is referencing line 4 in this code

```
@IBAction func deleteSubjectButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "newKnowledge")
    query.whereKey("subject", equalTo: (incomingHeader))
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {

                object.deleteInBackground()
            }
        }
    })

}
```

I'd really appreciate help solving this error. He has no idea why it's happening, and it isn't happening on his machine.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening to me as well with my Xcode 7.1.1.  I'm guessing it is being up-to-date that is causing this bug on just one machine.

The solution is to change the line to this:

> query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects : [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?)-> Void in

Notice I changed PFObject to AnyObject.

Comment: Anyone figure out the fix for this? Just updated Xcode and can no longer build my project. Not a Swift dev, but another dev who had worked on the project did their portions in Swift, so I'm struggling to figure this one out.

Answer (score 2):

Update for swift3 :

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "newKnowledge")
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects : [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {

                object.deleteInBackground()
            }
        }
    })
```